# Why is the gurobi model infeasible?

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, gurobi

Get quite confused by the infeasible model output.

It seems easy to solve the model by hand, and every variable can be determined. Where did I go wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's infeasible because of constraint R27:

```
-qt[0] - It[0] + It[1] = -257
```

`qt[0]` is 0 because of constraints `GC1` and `R56`. `It[0]` is fixed to 72 and that leaves `It[1]` to be -185 but `It[1]` is a non-negative variable so it cannot take this value.

Please consider that variables are non-negative by default.

Comment: WOW, I didn't notice that Gurobi has such a default setting. I guess that's why I cannot find the problem from the variable claim: 'It=m.addVars(FI[N-1],vtype=GRB.INTEGER,name='It')'.  THANK YOU, wish you stay healthy and safe.